# Automatically expand row heights in Excel when referenced from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

Suppose I am having two sheets where on *sheet 1* is this kind of data (different length of information within one row):

It might be lot of text that is "wrapped" to fit in a row (decently)

[image]

But, when I try to reference the same text, or try to use some formula for instance INDEX/MATCH to get me the same text, I am failing to get proper ROW Height...so I must adjust manually *sheet 2* rows to fit nicely from heights...

[image]

Is there a way in Excel to automatically make these row expansions? Without taking a manual action every time because I won't be always sure how long it will be my original text...

Answer (score 2):

You could add something into the Worksheet_Change event

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.WrapText = True
    Target.EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```

It might get annoying if it runs after every change for every cell, so you should add more if statements to limit which cells trigger the code.

Comment: Hmm but what if I have more cells like that? Like more different rows, not always the same...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The event will run after every cell gets a value or is cleared. It will ensure text wraps on cell width instead of being a single line. And `.EntireRow.AutoFit` tells the row height to automatically adjust to fit the wrapped text.

Comment: Yes this is great when I am typing something in my data sheet (sheet1), but it didn't work on second sheet2 where I referenced some cells or used formula to pull the data....

Comment: You can put it in `ThisWorkBook` module so that it will be triggered for all sheets. Change the first line from `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` to `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`